# OkHttp: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static content

Tags: android, okhttp

I am following up an example on this [link](https://gsaar.me/tutorial/android-tutorial-part-5-using-okhttp/) I get the error:

> Non-static method 'newCall(com.squareup.okhttp.Request) cannot be referenced from a static content

On this line `Call call = OkHttpClient.newCall(request);`

this is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String requestUrl = " http://iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?format=json";
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestUrl).build();
    TextView text1;
    public static final MediaType JSON = 
        MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    }

    call = OkHttpClient.newCall(request);

}
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: call it this way `client.newCall(request);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already created a client. Instead of

```
call = OkHttpClient.newCall(request);
```

your code should look like this:

```
call = client.newCall(request);
```

You need the created reference of the client.

Answer (score 2):

> Non-static method 'newCall(com.squareup.okhttp.Request)

the error means that you are trying to call a method of a class, which requires an object's instance, like the method is marked static. In your case `newCall` is a `not-static` method of `OkHttpClient`, hence it requires an instance of `OkHttpClient` to be accessed.